# Trouble running 2 devices on a single 12VDC power source

Tags: power-supply

I am using a dual connections to bring 12VDC power to both a video camera and a telescope mount.  Both devices are supplied by the same 12V 5A transformer and I am using a split VDC power cord that I bought from Amazon.

Both devices power on OK, but when I press a button to run positioning servomotors on the telescope, the camera cuts out.

I want to use a single transformer because of convenience.  FYI, both scope and camera come supplied with 12VDC 2A transformers.  Also using a Kill-a-Watt meter to measure each device separately, I determined that the resting amps for both were about 0.1A, and when I activate the motors the amps on the scope the amperage came up to 0.3A (the camera for its part is just a constant on video signal NTSC).

If there is some kind of amperage spike when I work the motors, is there a component that I can insert in my hookup that will keep the camera happy and prevent it from shutting off?

Comment: A transformer doesn't supply DC.

Comment: Do you mean you have a power supply, or just a transformer? If your power supply is 12VDC 5A, then I do not see any reason why it would not work properly. Check your wiring.

Answer (score 1):

Servo motors might have peak currents 5x average when moving so a battery near servo or supercap or a 1mF 16V cap might help prevent the line drop that the camera sees.   Use heavier cables ? Or a better transformer with lower winding losses.

Comment: Thanks, David, for the suggestions. I will look into inserting a capacitor right away. Is there a handy module that attaches in line into a 12VDC power cord?

Comment: @Doug_in_VA your capacitor should be from the power input pin to ground, as close to the end device as possible (not the power supply end, the device end of the cable)

Answer (score 1):

I recently dealt with a similar problem.  A camera wouldn't power up reliably at the end of a long cable run.

Upon attaching my DSO, I found that the power supply voltage was sagging by several volts for a few hundred microseconds when the camera was commanded to turn on.

The cure was simple: we installed 25,000 uF 25V capacitors right next to the cameras.  No more problems.

Comment: Wow, 25mF for a bit of decoupling!? that's a bit overkill, only a few millifarads would have done the trick. Nice job though lol

Comment: The cameras are installed in locations that are extremely difficult to reach.  Overkill was way, way better than having an unhappy customer.  I think that my testing showed that 5,000 uF wasn't enough and 10,000 uF seemed to work reliably.  So I doubled it.  The extra cost was insignificant compared to the cost of even one service trip.

Comment: what was your power supply? The problem can arise when putting too much capacitance on the line, especially if you are doing multiple 25mF caps, certain types of supplies may detect a short circuit condition and never do anything. I had this happen on the supply to my LED strobe array, which had 81mF capacitance on it

Answer (score -1):

Working Solutions:-

1) Use distributed topology instead of single regulator, use 2 regulators. Or use DC-DC switching regulator with 2-3 amp current ratting.It will work definitely.

Thank you.